# Is the ideology of middle eastern immigrants incompatible with western civilization?

Tags: europe, geopolitics, immigration, illegal-immigration

With all the mass immigration happening in europe, the recent paris attacks, and videos such as this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKp6GV69MT4), I've been getting increasingly unsettled. I've heard that the vast majority of these immigrants aren't even syrian refugees, and are just "freeloading" in a sense to get into better countries.

The video I linked, and in fact most opinions I read around the internet, portray them as violent and barbaric people who are unable to accommodate to civilized life. Another popular opinion I see floating around, the one I came here to ask about, is that the ideology of these immigrants (islam), and their lower performance on intelligence tests suggests that they will overpopulate european countries, become a majority, and scrap all european laws for "sharia law". This will spiral into unending wars like the ones currently occurring in the middle east.

Essentially, they suggest that islam is a destructive ideology that doesn't allow for scientific progress, rejects egalitarianism (with respect to women and non-muslims), promotes violence towards non-muslims, and will lead to the impoverishment of any nation whose population believes in the ideology.

I find this very scary, and I have many muslim friends who don't support any of what I mentioned above. I came here in hopes that some of you would refute the validity of these opinions and reveal them as the ignorant, racist, and unfounded opinions that I hope they are.

Comment: This isn't a site to refute youtube rants or explain why Facebook rumors aren't usually based on any sort of reality. Not that it's not politically related, but, well, it'd be a never-ending process to try and explain why the rants of social media folks are usually just FUD.

Comment: One suggestion I have is to find some reliable sources and read what they have to say on these issues. For me personally, I trust what newspapers like the Wall Street Journal, the New York Times, and NPR have to say because they are bound by their journalistic reputations to thoroughly research what they write about and either avoid taking sides in issues or being up-front about it when they do. They're much more reliable then memes on Facebook, which anybody can write and post without being held accountable.

Comment: It's not true of course but even if it were, a very simple solution (that I think should be implemented regardless) would be to allow everyone in provided they convert to atheism and pass exams in certain subjects. So, just let all the Mexicans, the Afghans, Pakistanis etc. etc. who all want to start a new life in the West in, put them in closed facilities where they need to pass rigorous exams and then we'll let highly qualified people converted to radical atheism in. The World would convert to atheism in blink of an eye if my plan were implemented.

Comment: Islam is not one thing. Muslims like to act like there's only one true Islam, but the reality is that there are many interpretations and one is just as valid as any other. So a particular interpretation of Islam might promote violence, but others won't.

Answer (score 4):

People tend to forget that anyone can write whatever they want on the internet, and there is no burden of proof. Ideas that stoke fear tend to go viral, and become accepted as fact. Take a step back and try to analyze what you are hearing: For example, "Refugees score lower on intelligence tests." Who is administering the tests? The boat runners as they navigate the Mediterranean with overcrowded boats? This idea seems incredible to me, and I believe it is very likely that it was made up by someone attempting to dehumanize the immigrants. This is a common tactic used by people who want to justify their discrimination against another group.

You are afraid of the teachings of Islam. Do you trust your Muslim friends? You have a great opportunity to learn about Islam if you have friends that are willing to explain things to you.

ISIS has twisted and perverted the teachings of Islam to support their own agenda. The vast majority of the world's Muslims disagree with them and do not support them. Every religion has its extremists that try to use their misinterpretation of their religion's teachings to justify their own actions.

Comment: -1. ISIS did not in any way "pervert" Islam. If you go read Atlantic's "What does ISIS want" article, they explain in detail that ISIS is pretty much the purest form of Islam, by design. Doesn't mean they are in the moral or ethical right, but they ARE right doctrinally. (the same applies to other religions as well - the modern "more civilized" versions are the "perverted" versions, even if they are clearly preferable).

Comment: @user4012 that's a technicality that probably applies to all religions fairly equally. I think it's understood to refer to 'modern' interpretations of Islam. In the modern age, any religion that is fundamentalist in that they observe their written doctrine as literal is perverting the modern attitudes. So one has to put the phrase 'perversion' into modern times.

Comment: @user4012 ISIS _does_ pervert Islam. Their "faith" isn't Islam, it's anarchy. They have no goal but to destroy humanity...including their own brothers and sisters.

Comment: @AleksandrH that's a bad example because Anarchy isn't about messing stuff up but removing illegitimate hierarchy.

Comment: @user45891 Good point, I understand. I didn't  know what other word to use though besides "terrorism", which is pretty self explanatory on its own :D

Comment: @AleksandrH - terroruism isn't an ideology. It's a tactic (unless you're Joker. But we live in a real world, not a Nolan film).

Comment: @user4012 Okay...but nobody said it was an ideology.

Comment: It's not about violence. There is something in the core beliefs of Muslims (and not just the extremists ones, but of all) which makes them incompatible with a secular society. Read this http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8316/should-muslims-in-a-secular-democracy-try-to-make-it-an-islamic-state  it's not from a far-right website but from stackexchange.

Answer (score 4):

As a commentary on the main paragraph:

***Essentially, they suggest that islam is a destructive ideology that doesn't allow for scientific progress,***

And yet Islamic nations were a beacon of scientific progress during the european dark ages, we are working to suppress Iran's nuclear progress, Dubai is a tehnological marvel, and a Turk won this year's nobel prize for Chemistry. And- well - the Syrian, Iranian, and Jordanian coders that I work with would laugh at this assertion.

To quote Mohammed:

“Seeking knowledge is compulsory on every Muslim.”

“wisdom is the lost property of the believer.”

“whoever follows a path seeking knowledge, Allah will make his path to paradise easy.”

***rejects egalitarianism (with respect to women and non-muslims),***

More true, especially the more devout versions. That being said, Saddam (a secular muslim) had women in senior positions, and even a Christian deputy prime minister for decades. Muslim nations like Pakistan, Sri Lanka, Bangladesh, etc. have elected female heads of state. In contrast, I don't see the Catholic church bending on female priests any time soon, and there are lost of stories of ultra-orthodox jews refusing to sit next to women on planes, or assaulting women in Isreal for dressing immodestly. So is it more patriarchal - hell yes, especially as it comes to rules on divorce, custody, property. but it is also not consistent across Muslim nations with many making strides towards better equality, and many backsliding as well.

***promotes violence towards non-muslims,***

Islam itself? No. Some practitioners? Yes. More than almost any other religion these days? Probably yes.

***and will lead to the impoverishment of any nation whose population believes in the ideology.***

Dubai, Kuwait, Kuala Lumpur, Turkey, The Maldives, Thailand's economy is growing - not falling, as is Bosnia's, Kosovos's and many others. Do bear in mind that many muslim countries are either resource-poor, or in parts of the world where their economies are on par with the neighborhood. In Europe they have recently emerged from Soviet rule. Both Muslim and Christian countries on the Horn of Africa are poor, and struggling to rebound from crippling colonial rule. I think you can leave God out of their struggles.

Comment: Last paragraph — Thailand's economy is, indeed, growing, but the country also suffers from [terrorist attacks](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-34369840). This also includes unrest in the Southern provinces, directly associated with radical Islamism.